# MainActivity cannot be cast to Fragment

Tags: java, android

Im working on this project. When i run the program it have some runtime errors and app does not appears in emulator. it show the message app stopped. I think there is a error in OnAttach method. I tried many ways to solve the issue but nothing works.I'm new to Android  development please help me to solve the  issue.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.workout, PID: 26059
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.workout/com.example.user.workout.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.user.workout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.user.workout.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.user.workout.WorkoutListFragment$WorkoutListListener
        at com.example.user.workout.WorkoutListFragment.onAttach(WorkoutListFragment.java:53)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1340)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1372)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1659)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1905)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3715)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:114)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.user.workout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

---

```
package com.example.user.workout;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class WorkoutListFragment extends ListFragment {


    static interface WorkoutListListener{

     void  itemClicked(long id);
    };

    private WorkoutListListener listener;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        String [] names = new String[Workout.workouts.length];
        for(int i =0; i < names.length;i++)
        {
            names[i] = Workout.workouts[i].getName();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
          inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {

        super.onAttach(activity);
       this.listener = (WorkoutListListener)activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        if(listener!=null)
        {
            listener.itemClicked(id);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.example.user.workout;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public  void  itemClicked(long id)
    {

        WorkoutDetialFragment detials = new WorkoutDetialFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        detials.setWorkoutId(id);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,detials);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity should implement `*WorkoutListListener*` interface and override its method `itemClicked()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WorkoutListListener {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

   @Override
   public void itemClicked(long id){
      // handle your click here 
   }

}
```